# container in main body is overlapping my side nav

Tags: html, css

here is my side nav code

```
<style>

    /* The side navigation menu */

    .sidenav {

        height: 50%; /* 100% Full-height */

        width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */

        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */

        z-index: 50; /* Stay on top */

        top: 0;

        right: 0;

        background-color: #111; /* Black*/

        overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */

        padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */

        transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */

    }



    /* The navigation menu links */

    .sidenav a {

        padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;

        text-decoration: none;

        font-size: 12px;

        color: #818181;

        display: block; 

        transition: 0.3s

    }



    /* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */

    .sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{

        color: #f1f1f1;

        background:#3797dd;

    }



    /* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */

    .sidenav .closebtn {

     top:0;

     right:25px;

     padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;

     text-decoration: none;

     font-size: 12px;

     color: #818181;

     display: block;

     transition: 0.3s

   /* position: absolute;

    top: 0;

    right: 25px;

    font-size: 36px;

    margin-left: 50px;*/

}
/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */

#main {

    transition: margin-left .5s;

    padding: 20px;

}



/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */

@media  screen and (max-height: 450px) {

    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}

    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}

}   

</style>
```

check www.dev.zulwa.com

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Your link no longer works.

Comment: Also, post your HTML.

Comment: the link is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your CSS :

```
.navbar {z-index : 99999 }
```

Comment: thanks , it works fine now, i saw my mistake after seeing this because i was using laravel i was not able to pick my mistake on time, but this just solved my issue , thanks @Temani Afif

Comment: but then, the nav bar is ahead my page loader , how can i make it stay behind the page loader everything the page is loading , because right now the nav bar display while the page is loading.

Comment: try to deacrease the value of z-index ... maybe the loader is having a low one .. try only 999 or even 99

Comment: i am having issues with the same sidenav on IOs, but its ok on other browser on android only overlapping on IOs browser, what can i do.

Answer (score 0):

here is my html code

× Close      
            Agent Finder

            How ZULWA Works

            Contact Us

```
      <a style="height: 40px; margin-top: -15px;"><span style="font-size:13px; cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()"><span>&#9776;</span> </span></a>

      <script>
        function openNav() {
          document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
        }

        function closeNav() {
          document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        }

        function openNav() {
          document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)";
        }

        /* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
        function closeNav() {
          document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
      </script>
    </li>
```